# How can I remove all but certain words from a column with alphanumerical values in my dataframe?

Tags: r

So I have a column in a dataframe with all this info but I want to filter it and remove every word before the word "Pericarida" for every line of the column, including removing the word "Pericarida" as well.

```
1.KU189316.1.2308 Eukaryota Opisthokonta Holozoa Metazoa (Animalia) Eumetazoa Bilateria Arthropoda Crustacea Malacostraca Eumalacostraca Peracarida Thermosphaeroma subequalum

2.EU414446.1.2220 Eukaryota Opisthokonta Holozoa Metazoa (Animalia) Eumetazoa Bilateria Arthropoda Crustacea Malacostraca Eumalacostraca Peracarida Betamorpha africana

3.JF699592.1.2323 Eukaryota Opisthokonta Holozoa Metazoa (Animalia) Eumetazoa Bilateria Arthropoda Crustacea Malacostraca Eumalacostraca Peracarida Scutuloidea maculata
```

The expected result should be something like this, but as of now I have no idea how to do it.
Thank you in advance for any responses.

```
1.Thermosphaeroma subequalum

2.Betamorpha africana

3.Scutuloidea maculata
```

Comment: using `gsub`,  `gsub(".*Peracarida (.*)","\\1",string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is `sub` to capture the digits followed by a dot (`\\d+\\.`) at the beginning (`^`) of the string, then capture the characters after the 'Peracarida' followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`).  In the replacement, use the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the captured group

```
sub("^(\\d+\\.).*\\sPeracarida\\s+(.*)$", "\\1\\2", str1)
#[1] "1.Thermosphaeroma subequalum" "2.Betamorpha africana"    
#[3]    "3.Scutuloidea maculata"
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the OP wanted to select the number at the beginning too.  If that is not needed, then just do

```
sub(".*\\bPeracarida\\s*", "", str1)
#[1] "Thermosphaeroma subequalum" "Betamorpha africana"  
#[3] "Scutuloidea maculata"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("1.KU189316.1.2308 Eukaryota Opisthokonta Holozoa Metazoa (Animalia) Eumetazoa Bilateria Arthropoda Crustacea Malacostraca Eumalacostraca Peracarida Thermosphaeroma subequalum", 
"2.EU414446.1.2220 Eukaryota Opisthokonta Holozoa Metazoa (Animalia) Eumetazoa Bilateria Arthropoda Crustacea Malacostraca Eumalacostraca Peracarida Betamorpha africana", 
"3.JF699592.1.2323 Eukaryota Opisthokonta Holozoa Metazoa (Animalia) Eumetazoa Bilateria Arthropoda Crustacea Malacostraca Eumalacostraca Peracarida Scutuloidea maculata"
)
```